# Show the number of close votes next to the button in the CV queue

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, review, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I have been reviewing close votes - and I think I'm doing pretty good.

There's one problem.

When reviewing, I am presented with four buttons:

> <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> <kbd>Close</kbd> <kbd>Edit</kbd> <kbd>Skip</kbd>

That's great. Except for audits.

I kind of like to see how many close votes there are *currently*. Since there is no other way to get this info, I tend to click the <kbd>Close</kbd> button - with no intention to close, but just wanting to see how many votes there are currently.

This trips me up on a *ton* of audits. I see a good looking post come through and think, 'Huh. Did someone really vote to close, or was this a flag?' Then the audit gets me.

So, my proposal is:

### Show the number of close votes next to the close button.

Something like this:

> <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> <kbd>Close (3)</kbd> <kbd>Edit</kbd> <kbd>Skip</kbd>

Or

> <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> <kbd>Close</kbd><sub>*3*</sub> <kbd>Edit</kbd> <kbd>Skip</kbd>

Comment: Instead of just clicking "close", can't you go to the question itself to see how many votes there were? (I'm not disagreeing with your entire post, just wondering why you clicked to close instead of going out of the queue for a second)

Comment: @sim It's faster! :)

Comment: Also, it's not very fun to work with tabs on Mobile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you think the question should be closed, click close.

If you don't think the question should be closed, click "leave open".

Sadly, some folks base their close-voting decisions on how other people vote and *not* on whether or not the question has serious problems that make it unsuitable for the site. So we intentionally omitted the close vote count in /review in hopes of discouraging this to some small degree.

If you need to know how other people voted in order to decide whether a given question should be closed, you should not be reviewing questions for closure.

Comment: It's not 'need to know', it's 'nice to know'. I'm not one of those that close everything I see with 4 votes - so please don't take that privilege away. Thanks, though.